# Type conversion issue in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I'm trying something (originally comes from [here](http://forum.brackeys.com/thread/what-are-the-differences-between-stack-and-heap-memory-allocation-c/)) about Heap and Pointer on C# Console project. And my program looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Win32
{
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr malloc(int size);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int free(IntPtr region); //Change IntPtr befroe free method to int ---update---
}

public class Program
{
    public unsafe void Heap()
    {
        int* num1, num2, answer;
        num1 = Win32.malloc(sizeof(int));
        *num1 = 999; // 999 should be the value stored at where pointer num1 refers to

        num2 = Win32.malloc(sizeof(int));
        *num2 = 1; // 1 should be the value stored at where pointer num2 refers to

        answer = Win32.malloc(sizeof(int));
        *answer = *num1 + *num2; // 1000 should be the value of pointer answer's reference

        Console.WriteLine(*answer); // 1000?
        Win32.free(num1);
        Win32.free(num2);
        Win32.free(answer);
    }
}
```

After debugging, got error message says:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IntPtr' to 'int*'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Win32.free(System.IntPtr)' has some invalid arguments

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int*' to 'System.IntPtr'
```

My questions here are why can't i use IntPtr before malloc and free, since both method return void? What changes should i make on my codes?
Thank you for help.

---Update---

change:    `public static extern IntPtr free(int hWnd);` to public static `extern int free(IntPtr region);` , `free(*num)` to `free(num)`

gives extra 'CS1502' and 'CS1503' two errors.

---second Update---
C# deal heap thing automatically. There is no equivalent of malloc in C#. It's a dead end. T_T

Comment: `are you missing a cast?`

Comment: @Rob The problem is that I don't think i miss a cast. And i don't know how to convert a void to int.

Answer (score 3):

A few mistakes:

in C/C++

```
void * malloc(int sizeToAllocate);
int free(void * region);
```

you pass into `free` the value returned by `malloc`. Thus your imports should be:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr malloc(int size); 

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int free(IntPtr region);
```

and consequently your freeing code should then become:

```
 var num1Ptr = Win32.malloc(sizeof(int));
 int * num1 = (int*) num1Ptr.ToPointer();

 ...

 var num2Ptr = Win32.malloc(sizeof(int));
 int * num2 = (int*) num2Ptr.ToPointer();

 ...

 var answerPtr = Win32.malloc(sizeof(int));
 int * answer = (int*) answerPtr.ToPointer();

 ...

 Win32.free(num1Ptr);
 Win32.free(num2Ptr);
 Win32.free(answerPtr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. It helps me better understand the way Platform Invoke works, and my mistake about free(pointer) instead of free(value). However, it gives extra two errors 'CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Win32.free(System.IntPtr)' has some invalid arguments' and 'CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int*' to 'System.IntPtr''.

Comment: You are right, you possibly could have simply done a simple `Win32.free(IntPtr(num1));` but the more rigorous approach is the updated solution.

Comment: I found my problem, malloc cannot be found in user32.dll or other reference, it doesn't have any equivalent in C# . Stupid as I run into the dead end and kept banging my head on the wall. T_T.